# Python treat module name as 'NoneType'

Tags: python, object, module

I have a piece of code that behaves strangely.

At the beginning, I import a module, which is a python binding for a C library.

```
try:
    import pyccn
except:
    print "ERROR: PyCCN is not found"
    exit(1)
```

Later in my code, I use pyccn module to do quite a lot stuff, and it was working as expected (almost). Now after working correctly for quite a while, it gives me the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./ndn-ls-keys.py", line 185, in upcall
     if kind == pyccn.UPCALL_CONTENT_UNVERIFIED:
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'UPCALL_CONTENT_UNVERIFIED'
```

So it say 'pyccn' is NoneType!!
But it was working, I mean the same function that includes line 185 was called multiple times before the error happens. And the error happens consistently. I didn't redefine 'pyccn', was just using 'pyccn.foo(), pyccn.bar(), etc'.

What are the possible reasons that this could happen?

P.S. The error happens at the end of my script. If I put a time.sleep(10) there, then it happens after the sleeping...

Thanks!

Comment: There's probably no way to answer this without seeing the rest of the code- can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I would like to... But it requires quite a bit dependency on PyCCN side.. Do you have any guess on the possible reasons that a module was treated as 'NoneType' object?

Comment: I think you have to be assigning `None` to the `pyccn` name somewhere in your code. If the `pyccn` module was never imported at all, you'd get a `NameError` for using an unknown name, rather than an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Has anything recently changed with your Python configuration or your PyCCN library? Any updates?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not reassigned as such at some point by accident? I can't think of another reason, though I'd be excited to learn of another. Could you at least show the Pyrhon side of the code? (and have you tried searching the code for lines like `pyccn =` or `pyccn=`?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I added a link to the code

Comment: @Blckknght I was suspecting that too.. but I really could find anything suspicious about assigning None to pyccn..

Comment: Can you use print statements to determine whether it evaluates to None only within that method, or in the method that calls it as well?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I tried. 'pyccn' was a module at line 185 until the error happens, when it mysteriously became 'None'

Comment: @zzk What's the value of `kind` being passed into the `upcall` method? In particular the output of `kind.__class__.__name__`

Comment: @cwgem 'kind' has no problem here. the problem is 'pyccn' becomes None somehow.

Comment: `pyccn` uses threading.  It's a long shot, but perhaps there's a strange interaction between threads on shutdown as the destructors are called?

Comment: @AustinPhillips I somehow managed to make the problem go away, but don't know how it fixed the problem.. see my answer below

Comment: @AustinPhillips: The call `ccn.expressInterest (name, slurp,...)` is passing a `Slurp` instance that references the module. If `upcall` is running in a separate thread, that's a likely scenario.

Comment: Try running your script with `PYTHONVERBOSE=2` to monitor the shutdown cleanup, when attributes and modules are cleared by setting them to `None`.

Comment: @eryksun I saw a lot of output (indeed verbose..) And I saw pyccn gets set to None at some point (it's before the cleaning of pyccn.Key and some other part of pyccn, not sure if this is a problem). Additionally, If 'time' was imported at beginning, it was cleaned up twice (beginning of cleaning and end of cleaning); the output to screen was flushed to the screen before cleaning finished perhaps due to the error. if 'time' was imported inside function (which fixed the problem), it was cleaned up only once, and the output to the screen was flushed to screen after cleaning finished.

Comment: To debug threading, try setting `threading._VERBOSE = True` before importing `pyccn`. Also, in debug print statements (e.g. in `Slurp.upcall`) you can print the current thread's name, `threading.current_thread().name` (e.g. "MainThread", "Thread-1").

Answer (score 2):

I somehow solved this problem. 
Originally, immediately below the import for PyCCN, I have two other imports:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import time
```

So the imports are global to this file.

Once I moved these two imports inside the function where they are actually used, the problem went away!! The move is the only change and I don't know the reason behind this fix.

Perhaps there is some conflicts between the imports due to some problem in pyccn module? (I assume the standard libraries are not responsible for this problem).

Comment: Do you have a module of your own named `time`?

Comment: @nneonneo as far as I know, no.

Comment: I had nonetype errors at shutdown with no file name and no line number. I ended up fixing it by moving an import ag34401a_class from global to local. Perhaps it was trying to free the same global objects twice?